# Accessing directive scope in controller using service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I was trying to access a value returned by a directive in my controller. I tried with a service. It's not working; it seems like the updated directive's return value is not picked up by the controller.

Here's my code:

#### HTML

```html
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <input type="file" file-reader="fileContent" />
        <div>{{fileContent}}</div>
     </body>
   </html>
```

#### Controller

```js
 myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,sharedTrialService) {
    $scope.newValue = sharedTrialService.TrialInfo;  
    $scope.newData  = $scope.newValue.data; 
 });
```

#### Directive

```js
myApp.directive('fileReader', function(sharedTrialService) {
  return {
    scope: {
      fileReader:"="
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      $(element).on('change', function(changeEvent) {
        var files = changeEvent.target.files;
        if (files.length) {
          var r = new FileReader();
          r.onload = function(e) {
              var contents = e.target.result.replace(/\r\n|\r/g,'\n');

              scope.$apply(function () {
                var lines=contents.split('\n');


                scope.fileReader = lines;
                sharedTrialService.TrialInfo.data=scope.fileReader;
              });
          };
          r.readAsText(files[0]);
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

#### Service

```js
 myApp .factory('sharedTrialService', function () {
       return {
                 TrialInfo: {
                 data: " "
                }
              };
    })
});
```

How can I access the directive's `sharedTrialService.TrialInfo.data` from my controller?

Answer (score 0):

With `$scope.newValue = sharedTrialService.TrialInfo.data;` you are just assign a string to `newValue`, but you need to assign a reference, so you need to assign an object or an array. So change it to `$scope.newValue = sharedTrialService.TrialInfo;` and access your data via `newValue.data`.

**EDIT**

Use `$watch` in your controller for debugging:

```
$scope.$watch('newValue', function() {
    console.log('newValue:', $scope.newValue);
}, true);

$scope.$watch('newData', function() {
    console.log('newData:', $scope.newData);
}, true);
```

I think, `$scope.newValue` should change as it's an object reference, but `$scope.newData` is just a string value and is the same as stated above, it won't change. So, you always need to access it via `$scope.newValue.data`.

---

From console

```
newValue: Object {data: " "}
newData:  
newValue: Object {data: Array[6]}
```

`$scope.newData` won't update, because it has still just the reference to that string value.

In your service you define your string value `" "`, `TrialInfo.data` holds only a reference to that string value. With  `$scope.newData  = $scope.newValue.data;` you copy that reference to `$scope.newData`. In your directive you copy the reference of the filereader to `sharedTrialService.TrialInfo.data`, but `$scope.newData` has still the reference to that string value. `$scope.newData` and `TrialInfo.data` hold different references.

`$scope.newValue` holds a reference to the object `TrialInfo`. You can do everything with its properties, but the reference to that object remains unchanged. So, if the `data` property changed you can still access it via `$scope.newValue.data`.

Maybe I'm not the best to explain it.

Comment: $scope.newValue is getting me the updated object , but newValue.data is still null

Comment: it's coming like this $scope.trial  is giving  Object {data: Array[0]} and $scope.trial.data []. What can i do to get the array from $scope.trial

Comment: In your code I don't see where you call something like `r.readAsText(files[0])`, so `r.onload` is never called and `sharedTrialService.TrialInfo.data` is never set.

Comment: Thanks Brakebein,I have updated the code ,what I could see is the controller part is just running once initially and it is not updating after the directive gives new value. Can you please tell me what can I do for that

Comment: On debugging the controller , i could see only the newValue is getting updated, the newData is not even fired when the value gets changed.  I have pasted above the output from  my console on debugging.